Off-axis reflection and correction of spherical aberration
I'm trying to design an optical system but I'm hopeless. A picture is attached illustrating what I'm asking.
A spherical reflector with radius of curvature r and focus f=r/2 is refocused by a secondary mirror past the focus to converge fully at f', an angle pi/6 against the axis, and at the edge of the sphere plus some small gap epsilon. Problem illustration
What is the required shape of the curve in red?
A book reference that contains the mathematical framework for solving questions of this type would be awesome too!
